# A file of all Korean language words?

Tags: language, dictionary

Is there an open data set file (not an open API) containing all (or almost all) Korean language words?
There are some famous Korean dictionaries such as the Standard Korean Dictionary published by the National Institute of the Korean Language (국립국어원 표준국어대사전).

I know there are some Transformers-based language models' vocab files but they are not what I want because they contain some non-standard form of words.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a JSON dump of the Korean entries of the English Wiktionary: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Korean/index.html

There are also the extracted Korean entries of other Wiktionaries here: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html